# How do I make an image be at the top of my website but make sure it shows up the same for everyone?

Tags: html, css, list, web, navigationbar

Im making a simple website that will have a top bar that will have the logo placed beside the navigation bar and the navigation bar placed on an image with the logo of a wood pattern that stretches horizontally across the whole site. I cant seem to find the right way of making sure that the wood picture takes up the whole top for every computer out there, the image has a width of 3888px so its not like the entire width will be used up on most monitors, Im just looking for help on getting that to look right on the top of the page with the entire top bar being 200 px in height and however I am able to have a good looking top bar that is fully across on every monitor.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body{
                background-color:#F0E0B2;
            }
            img{
                position:absolute; 
                z-index:-2;
                left:0px;
                right:0px;
                top:0px;
            }
            img2{
                left:0px;
                top:0px;
            }
            ul{
                z-index:1
                list-style-type:none;
                margin-top:240px;
                margin-left:500px;
                padding:0;
                overflow:hidden;
            }
            li{
                float:left;
            }
            a:link,a:visited{
                width:120px;
                font-weight:bold;
                color:#FFFFFF;
                text-align:center;
                padding:10px;
                text-decoration:none;
                text-transform:uppercase;
            }
            a:hover,a:active{
                text-color:#B8B8B8 ;
            }
        </style>
    <body>
        <img src="navibar.png" width="3888px" height="275px"/>
        <img src="whitebird.png" width="250px" height="200px"/>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#music">Music</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<img src="navibar.png" width="3888px" height="275px"/>` as a background..

```
background:url('path/to/navibar.png');
```